# Error parsing the json data using regex in fluentd

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, fluentd

I have fluentd working perfectly fine and is able to publish data to elastic search. I modified the fluentd config file to tail a file, get the data and publish. Below is the source:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  format /^\[(?<logtime>[^\]]*)\] (?<name>[^ ]*) (?<title>[^ ]*) (?<id>\d*)$/
  time_key logtime
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z
  path /home/user/file
  tag first
</source>
```

If input is below data:

```
[2013-02-28 12:00:00 +0900] alice engineer 1
```

This is getting read by fluentd perfectly and is also published to elasticsearch.

I then modified the regex pattern to accept json data:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  format /(?:"Name":")(.*?)(?:")/ #CHANGE HERE
  time_key logtime
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z
  path /home/user/file
  tag first
</source>
```

So if input is:

```
{
    "Name":"Logger",
    "Type":"Logging"
}
```

Then there is no data on elasticsearch. Even the logs of the fluentd doesnt show any error or warning message. Is the regex pattern wrong. How can I resolve it.?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the pattern contain a named capturing group? Try `format /"Name"\s*:\s*"(?<name>[^"]*)"/`. Not sure, but [this seems relevant](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/parser_json).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi. I didnt get you by `pattern contain a named capturing group`. The json I am passing has the `Name`. I will try your approach and will let you know.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it worked. Can you explain a bit more about your regex pattern as I am newbie in it. Also if I want to include `Type` from my json data, what changes I'll have to make in regex pattern. Thankyou very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to get data out of json into elasticsearch. You may use a JSON parser to do the heavy lifting for you, see the [**Getting Data From Json Into Elasticsearch Using Fluentd**](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/recipe-json-to-elasticsearch) with the necessary details to get you started.

If you want to fix the regex approach you have, use

```
format /"Name"\s*:\s*"(?<name>[^"]*)"/
```

Note that `(?<name>...)` is a *named capturing group* that are used in Elastic Search to create fields with the same names. The pattern matches

- `"Name"` - a literal `"Name"` substring
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars
- `"` - a double quote
- `(?<name>[^"]*)` - Group "name" matching 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a double quote (not necessary though).

If you want to have `Type` as well in the same field, you may use

```
format /"(?:Name|Type)"\s*:\s*"(?<name>[^"]*)"/
```

where `(?:Name|Type)` is a non-capturing group matching either `Name` or `Type` substring (`|` is an alternation operator).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to Type in other field and Name in other field, how can I regex for that. Can you please refer me to some links where I can learn all this. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you need to add it to the regex like `/"Name"\s*:\s*"(?<name>[^"]*)",\s+"Type"\s*:\s*"(?<type>[^"]*)"/`, but probably, you can achieve the same in an easier way with [JSON Parser](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/recipe-json-to-elasticsearch).

Comment: Thankyou very much. It looks like it working but not working in case of nested json. Just wanted to make sure, is there any other format for nested jsons.?

Comment: I can't help you more with that since I believe you should be using JSON parser and get the items you need using JSON paths to the data you need to extract. Also, I think [this link](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/1146#issuecomment-237874341) may help. Also, [here is a Ruby plugin](https://gist.github.com/mark-adams/c4826e28f87d52c06b66) to extract nested JSON log messages from Docker logs.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help.